# MySql count() to return 0 if no records found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of posts on monthly basis. Now i need an array which contains total records of posts posted in each month. I tried below MySql query, Its working fine, but I was expecting 0(Zero) for months where there is no records. Here its not returning 0.

I read that COUNT() will not return '0', So how do i achieve this?

I tried IFNULL(), and COALESCE() but still getting the same result. Please help with this query. Thank You......

```
SELECT
count(id) as totalRec
FROM ('post')
WHERE year(date) =  '2013'
AND monthname(date) IN ('January', 'February', 'March') 
GROUP BY year(date)-month(date)
ORDER BY 'date' ASC
```

Got Result:

```
+----------+
| totalRec |
+----------+
|        7 |
|        9 |
+----------+
```

Expected Result (Where there is no posts for January):

```
+----------+
| totalRec |
+----------+
|        0 |
|        7 |
|        9 |
+----------+
```

Sample Data:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
| 24 | 2012-12-16 16:29:56 |
|  1 | 2013-02-25 14:57:09 |
|  2 | 2013-02-25 14:59:37 |
|  4 | 2013-02-25 15:12:44 |
|  5 | 2013-02-25 15:14:18 |
|  7 | 2013-02-26 11:31:31 |
|  8 | 2013-02-26 11:31:59 |
| 10 | 2013-02-26 11:34:47 |
| 14 | 2013-03-04 04:39:02 |
| 15 | 2013-03-04 05:44:44 |
| 16 | 2013-03-04 05:48:29 |
| 19 | 2013-03-07 15:22:34 |
| 20 | 2013-03-15 12:24:43 |
| 21 | 2013-03-16 16:27:43 |
| 22 | 2013-03-16 16:29:28 |
| 23 | 2013-03-16 16:29:56 |
| 11 | 2013-03-17 11:35:12 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Comment: can you give sample records where we can play with?

Comment: Your group by looks incorrect

Comment: @JW웃 I have edited my question with sample data..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no record for the month of `January` that is why you are getting no result. One solution that works is by joining a subquery with contains list of months that you want to be shown on the list.

```
SELECT count(b.id) as totalRec
FROM   (
            SELECT 'January' mnth
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'February' mnth
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'March' mnth
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN post b
            ON a.mnth = DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%M') AND
               year(b.date) =  '2013' AND 
               DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%M') IN ('January', 'February', 'March') 
GROUP  BY year(b.date)-month(b.date) 
ORDER  BY b.date ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0a6e/7)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╗
║ TOTALREC ║
╠══════════╣
║        0 ║
║        7 ║
║        9 ║
╚══════════╝
```

Comment: @JW I added April Month to the select list in your JSfiddle example, so result should be [0,7,9,0] but its showing [0,7,9]. Can you please see to it once? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0a6e/15

Comment: This really helped me get something done that is similar:--get count of pots used and next1
use plants
go
select a.pot, count(b.pot_info) as number from
(select pot_info as pot from pots
union
select next1 from pots)a
left join plants b on
a.pot=b.pot_info
group by a.pot
order by a.pot

Answer (score 5):

Did you try `IFNULL()` the right way? Maybe try `IFNULL(Count(id), 0)` in a `SELECT` clause with join.

Answer (score 5):

`COALESCE` is what you could use, if you have a table of dates and left joined against it. It goes left to right to return the first non null value.
Your group by does look a little nutty at the minute, I have adjusted it.

```
SELECT
COALESCE(count(id),0) as totalRec
FROM ('post')
LEFT JOIN dates
ON dates.date = post.date
WHERE year(date) =  '2013'
AND monthname(date) IN ('January', 'February', 'March') 
GROUP BY month(date), year(date)
ORDER BY 'date' ASC
```

Where dates table is..

```
DATE
2013-01-01 
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
etc....
```

See here : http://easywebapps.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/mysql-how-to-create-calendar-table.html

Comment: Sorry, I missed the date table creation bit, thats important

Answer (score 1):

If the result set had no posts during that time period, you won't get any results to count, hence why it doesn't show.

You would need to either join to another table that has all of the year months or fill in the data programmatically when the results are returned. I can't think of another way to do this, but perhaps it's possible.

Also, as others have said, separate the group by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this::

```
SELECT
  count(id) as totalRec
  IF(id NULL, 0, id) As IdList
FROM ('post')
 WHERE year(date) =  '2013'
  AND monthname(date) IN ('January', 'February', 'March') 
  GROUP BY year(date)-month(date)
ORDER BY 'date' ASC
```

**To return 0 instead of null in MySQL
 
USE**

> SELECT id, IF(age IS NULL, 0, age) FROM tblUser

**USE with count() having join of 2 tables**

> Tables

**tblA**

```
tblA_Id    Name     
-----------------
    1       HSP     
    2       MANI     
    3       MEET     
    4       user    
    5       jaani
```

**tblB**

```
tblB_Id    SongName  tblA_Id
 -----------------------------
    1        song1     3
    2        song2     3
    3        song3     1
    4        song4     1
    5        song4     5
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    tblA.tblA_Id,
    tblA.Name,
    tblC.SongCount,
    IF(tblC.SongCount IS NULL, 0, tblC.SongCount) As noOfSong
  FROM  tblA
    LEFT JOIN
    (   
        SELECT 
            ArtistId,count(*) AS SongCount 
        FROM 
            tblB  
        GROUP BY 
            ArtistId
    ) AS tblC
    ON 
        tblA.tblA_Id = NoOfSong.ArtistId
```

Result is

```
 tblA_Id    Name     SongCount   noOfSong
 -------------------------------------------
    5       jaani    1           1
    4       user     NULL        0
    3       MEET     2           2
    2       MANI     NULL        0
    1       HSP      2           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need query like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id),0) AS totid FROM table
```

vb example

```
Set count=Con.Execute("SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id),0) AS totid FROM table")
```

then write

```
<%=count("totid")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to simply you sql.
My old sql like this

```
select c.*, dynamic_count from channel c 
    left join (select channel_id, count(*) as dynamic_count from dynamic group by channel_id) d
             on c.id = d.channel_id;
```

and i got null if dynamic don't match.But if i change my sql like this:

```
select c.*, count(d.id) as dynamic_count from channel c
    left join dynamic d on c.id = d.channel_id
    group by c.id;
```

I got 0 if no dynamics match;
Hope it's helpful!