# Group by month and return 0 if data not found

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to fix my query for days now :(. 
It is supposed to group by month and return 0 if record is not found. 
An example:

```
    SELECT MONTH(created_at) AS month_num, 
DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b') AS month_name, COUNT(*) AS total_num 
    FROM table WHERE user_id=1384249399168
    GROUP BY MONTH(created_at) ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Result:

```
month_num       month_name       total_num
     8            Aug                 20 
     7            Jul                 15
     5            May                 39
     2            Feb                 10
     1            Jan                 8
```

Espected Result:

```
month_num       month_name       total_num
         12           Dec                 0
         11           Nov                 0
         10           Oct                 0
         9            Sep                 0
         8            Aug                 20 
         7            Jul                 15
         6            Jun                 0
         5            May                 39
         4            Apr                 0
         3            Mar                 0
         2            Feb                 10
         1            Jan                 8
```

I have tried a lot of answers especially this [MySql count() to return 0 if no records found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636433/mysql-count-to-return-0-if-no-records-found) but without success.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post solved my problem. 
I had to create a table which contains all the 12 months.

[mysql select the count of records for every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841549/mysql-select-the-count-of-records-for-every-month)
Thanks anyone especially @Turdaliev

Comment: You could also use a UNION - or even a utility table of integers (0-9) - or (even better idea) handle the logic of missing months at the application level (e.g. with a bit of php)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested but it should work:

```
SELECT MONTH(created_at) AS month_num, 
DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b') AS month_name, ifnull(count(*),0) AS total_num 
    FROM table WHERE user_id=1384249399168
    GROUP BY MONTH(created_at) ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: You know, there is a function for that. It's called COALESCE.

Comment: @Turdaliev Sorry it did not work. I return the same result without the 0 for months which do not have data. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @TurdalievNursultan Thanks but still the same result.

Comment: @Strawberry I have tried COALESCE and IFNULL functions but for some reasons, it will not return 0 for months without data. Thanks

Comment: Try applying method used in the following link http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,514167