# How to group by month and return zero if no value for certain month?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

This is my mysql income table.

```
+----+------------------+---------------------------+------------+---------+
| id | title            | description               | date       | amount  |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+------------+---------+
|  1 | Vehicle sales up | From new sale up          | 2016-09-09 | 9999.99 |
|  2 | Jem 2 Sales      | From rathnapura store     | 2016-05-15 | 9545.25 |
|  3 | Jem 2 Sales 2    | From rathnapura store     | 2016-05-15 | 9545.25 |
|  4 | Jem 2 Sales 2    | From rathnapura store 234 | 2016-05-15 | 9545.25 |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+------------+---------+
```

The field 'date' is standard sql date. And I executed this query in order to take sum of incomes by month and return zero if no income from a certain month. I want zeros if no income from a certain month because i want to display these data in a chart.

This is the query.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) AS mName, MONTH(`date`) AS mOrder, ifnull(sum(amount),0) AS total_num FROM income GROUP BY mOrder ORDER BY mOrder DESC
```

But I only get a output like follows. No zeros if no values in other months. This is the output.

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| mName     | mOrder | total_num |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| September |      9 |   9999.99 |
| May       |      5 |  28635.75 |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

And I want other months in above table and total_num as zero. How can I do this? There's same kind of question there too. But no working answer.
[Group by month and return 0 if data not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319135/group-by-month-and-return-0-if-data-not-found)

Please help me to solve this issue. The language I use for this application is Node.JS :)

Comment: But you have only two month in your example, so result is quite predictable.

Comment: I think you will need some kind of Calandar Table, and join on it, then group by month

Comment: @user1016265 Yeah I have to months. But this doesn't matter I think. Because if the code is correct, other months should appear with zoro. No ? That's why I want. Imagine this is a accounting system and at the beginning of the year, we have income for only January. So other 11 months must come with 0 income. No ?

Comment: @user1016265 Please check this too. There's some kind of answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319135/group-by-month-and-return-0-if-data-not-found But not working properly.

Comment: @guiguiblitz   Please check this too. There's some kind of answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319135/group-by-month-and-return-0-if-data-not-found But not working properly.

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva If you have no records for corresponding month in your original table, MySQL won't make any magic for you with query what you showed us

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva you either have to use some extra table with all months, or mysql procedure might help, because you need a `LOOP` statement

Comment: @user1016265 yeap man. I think using another months table might help :) Thanks

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best resolved in the presentation layer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this it's not the best way to do it, but it will solve your problem. As a quick soution:

```
SELECT 'January' AS mName, 1 AS mOrder, COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS total_num 
FROM income i
WHERE month(i.date) = 1

UNION

SELECT 'February' AS mName, 2 AS mOrder, COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS total_num 
FROM income i
WHERE month(i.date) = 2

UNION

...and go on
```

Comment: I think that solution is possible even though it's a bit ugly :-)

Comment: This wont work because still you are selecting from the income - and maybe not all months are there..

Comment: It does not matter. Imagine you dont have any date on january. The first select will return 1 row: (January, 1, 0). When you use "SUM",  if you dont have records, it will return 1 row with null value, instead of no rows. Please try it before sayings it doesn't work. It's not an elegant way to do it, but it works as expected.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum as you can see in the documentation, sum return "null" if there is no record, and coalesce change null values to 0 in this case

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk Hey man, This code works. Doesn't matter the code is so huge. And can you tell me how's the processing speed. Imaging if there are lot of incomes in the table. Does it take a lot of time to process ? Because I think do this in database layer is fine because when we are doing this in front end or backend, this can take too long. no ?

Comment: In theory, the most efficient solution would be @GiladGreen solution. My solutions has some pennalties due the unions, because it has to do 12 operations. However i have test a similiar query on my side, and for 50.000 record it takes less a second. I would need to do more unit test to really check how much will it take with large data and how better GiladGreen Solution is. But I believe that, if it's not the best way to do it, it could work on real situation.

Comment: you need to add year also. if not jan from all the years will group together. and this is not the best way and not recommended at all as a programmer

Answer (score 3):

Have a table of all the months and then `left join` to your table:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(m.month) AS mName, 
    MONTH(m.month) AS mOrder, 
    ifnull(sum(amount),0) AS total_num 
from months m
left join income i
on m.month = i.date

GROUP BY mOrder 
ORDER BY mOrder DESC
```

If you don't want to create a `months` table then you can:

```
(select STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/03/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/07/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/09/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/10/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month union 
 select STR_TO_DATE('01/12/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') as month)
```

Comment: Collection means ???? A mysql table named 'months' ???? And what's 'm.date' you mentioned ?

Comment: How to connect these months you added later with the above query ???? A little help please.

Comment: I can create a months table too. Not a problem. Because I cannot understand how can I use those select queries you added later with your first SQL query. Can you tell me what are the fields I should add if i'm making a month table ?Or please explain me how to use those two queries together :)

Comment: Ya if you past all the second block ( nested selects) instead of the "months" in ` from months m`

Comment: Sure I will try that and tell you. Give me 1 min plz

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'm.date' in 'field list'

Comment: Gilad Green , This error occurred. Please check this GIST.

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva - ya - when you decided to use the nested selects then you should have changed the `m.date` to fit the field you are getting from that select... which is the `m.month`.

Comment: when I did so, total_num is getting 0. Always it's zero. Not getting the sum

Answer (score 0):

You should create a CALENDAR table, with the precision you need, in this case months.

```
+-----------+
| Month     |
+-----------+
| January   |   
| February  |      
.......
```

And Join on it