# Convert query to handle empty set results

Tags: mysql

My problem is I'm running a query where there is sometimes an empty set of results (nothing is returned). I need to modify the output so that hours with no data are still represented with the appropriate "0" count. The following documentation lists the query I'm using as well as sample output.

Current query being used:

```
select date(look) as "Day",concat(date_format(look, '%H'),':00') as "Hour", count(distinct(session_name)) as "Count"
from db.login_stats 
where look > '2015-10-06' 
group by date(look),concat(date_format(look, '%H'),':00');
```

Current Output:

```
+------------+-------+-------+
| Day        | Hour  | Count |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2015-10-07 | 09:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 10:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 11:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 12:00 |     2 |
| 2015-10-07 | 13:00 |     2 |
| 2015-10-07 | 14:00 |     2 |
| 2015-10-07 | 15:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 18:00 |     1 |
```

What I would like the output to resemeble:

```
+------------+-------+-------+
| Day        | Hour  | Count |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2015-10-07 | 00:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 01:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 02:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 03:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 04:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 05:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 06:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 07:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 08:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 09:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 10:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 11:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 12:00 |     2 |
| 2015-10-07 | 13:00 |     2 |
| 2015-10-07 | 14:00 |     2 |
| 2015-10-07 | 15:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 16:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 17:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 18:00 |     1 |
| 2015-10-07 | 19:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 20:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 21:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 22:00 |     0 |
| 2015-10-07 | 23:00 |     0 |
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636433/mysql-count-to-return-0-if-no-records-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no trivial way to do that that I know of, but it is achievable. The following query will print all 24 hours for each day that matches your WHERE clause (for instance, it will print the desired output for your current data, and if you insert an extra row with `look` equal to `2015-10-08` it will add 24 more rows to the output):

```sql
-- populate a table with 24 rows, one per hour

create table hours(hour time);
insert into hours values(0), (10000), (20000);
insert into hours select hour + 30000 from hours;
insert into hours select hour + 60000 from hours;
insert into hours select hour + 120000 from hours;

-- now this query will do what you want

select dates.d as "Day",dates.h as "Hour", count(distinct(session_name)) as "Count"
from db.login_stats RIGHT JOIN
    (
    SELECT date(look) as d, concat(date_format(hour, '%H'),':00') as h
    FROM login_stats CROSS JOIN hours
    WHERE date(look) > '2015-10-06' -- moved your WHERE here
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 1, 2
    ) dates
    ON date(look) = d AND concat(date_format(look, '%H'),':00') = h
group by dates.d, dates.h;
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what the hours Insert statements are doing. Can you please explain?

Comment: I just want to populate a table that has 24 rows, one per hour. One way to achieve that is to just execute 24 insert statements, or one statement with 24 rows. Instead I insert three rows with hours 0, 1 and 2, then I execute an insert SELECT that inserts three more rows: 3, 4 and 5, another INSERT SELECT to insert 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11, and the last one to insert remaining 12. It's a logarithmic way to populate a list of numbers. After you execute those statements `hours` will have 24 rows, one per hour.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!